# I can't see the custom thumbnail image in Wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails

I have a problem with wordpress thumb. I installed the last wordpress in localhost and I tried to create a new post with a thumb but when I save it, in the home doesn't appear this thumb.

See the following images:

http://i41.tinypic.com/ffalvk.jpg

http://i42.tinypic.com/6pn3g9.png

This is the image url:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/object/thumb.php?src=wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/5767096.jpg&w=300&h=200&zc=1&q=100
```

¿What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just trying here as I do not know what plugin is this. However, you can try changing the image URL to this:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/object/thumb.php?src=http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/5767096.jpg&w=300&h=200&zc=1&q=100
```

However, I would recommend you to use WordPress in-built **[Feature Image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)** function to set the thumbnail instead. That is, of course, if your theme allows it.

Comment: I just realized that the problem is in the theme. I'm using 'Object' theme and when I installed it, changed my post area. I want to use 'Feature Image' for fix it, or I'll try it. Thanks